# NodePort service does not accept connections/forward connection to pod without port-forwarding -- how to resolve this?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

So, I have deployed my service as a `NodePort` and connection requests (from my terminal) are not sent to the application without `port-forward`. Here are my specs:

```
$ kubectl get svc rhs-servicebase -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    getambassador.io/config: |
      apiVersion: ambassador/v1
      kind:  Mapping
      name:  http_referral-health-signal_mapping
      grpc: false
      prefix: /referral-health-signal/
      rewrite: /
      timeout_ms: 0
      service: rhs-servicebase:9000
      cors:
        origins: "*"
        headers: X-User-Agent, X-Grpc-Web, Content-Type, Authorization
        max_age: "1728000"
  creationTimestamp: "2022-08-31T22:32:28Z"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: servicebase
  name: rhs-servicebase
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "93013"
  uid: 84aba835-6399-49f4-be4f-4e6454d1bd7d
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.103.51.237
  clusterIPs:
  - 10.103.51.237
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - nodePort: 30001
    port: 9000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9000
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: rhs
    app.kubernetes.io/name: servicebase
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: NodePort
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

```
$ kubectl get deployment rhs-servicebase -o yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "1"
  creationTimestamp: "2022-08-31T22:32:28Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: rhs
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: servicebase
    helm.sh/chart: servicebase-0.1.5
  name: rhs-servicebase
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "93040"
  uid: 04af37db-94e0-42b3-91e1-56272791c70a
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: rhs
      app.kubernetes.io/name: servicebase
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: rhs
        app.kubernetes.io/name: servicebase
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: TZ
          value: UTC
        - name: LOG_FILE
          value: application.log
        - name: S3_BUCKET
          value: livongo-int-healthsignal
        - name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: aws-access-key-id
              name: referral-health-signal
        - name: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: aws-secret-access-key
              name: referral-health-signal
        image: localhost:5000/referral-health-signal:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: servicebase
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
          protocol: TCP
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - name: secret-referral-health-signal
        secret:
          defaultMode: 420
          items:
          - key: aws-access-key-id
            path: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
          - key: aws-secret-access-key
            path: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
          secretName: referral-health-signal
status:
  availableReplicas: 1
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2022-08-31T22:32:30Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2022-08-31T22:32:30Z"
    message: Deployment has minimum availability.
    reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Available
  - lastTransitionTime: "2022-08-31T22:32:28Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2022-08-31T22:32:30Z"
    message: ReplicaSet "rhs-servicebase-6f676c458c" has successfully progressed.
    reason: NewReplicaSetAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Progressing
  observedGeneration: 1
  readyReplicas: 1
  replicas: 1
  updatedReplicas: 1
```

```
$ kubectl get pod rhs-servicebase-6f676c458c-f2rw6  -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2022-08-31T22:32:28Z"
  generateName: rhs-servicebase-6f676c458c-
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: rhs
    app.kubernetes.io/name: servicebase
    pod-template-hash: 6f676c458c
  name: rhs-servicebase-6f676c458c-f2rw6
  namespace: default
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    controller: true
    kind: ReplicaSet
    name: rhs-servicebase-6f676c458c
    uid: 983b450e-4fe2-40fb-a332-a959d9b569bc
  resourceVersion: "93036"
  uid: 3dff4f66-8369-4855-a371-0fc2f37209a4
spec:
  containers:
  - env:
    - name: TZ
      value: UTC
    - name: LOG_FILE
      value: application.log
    - name: S3_BUCKET
      value: livongo-int-healthsignal
    - name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          key: aws-access-key-id
          name: referral-health-signal
    - name: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          key: aws-secret-access-key
          name: referral-health-signal
    image: localhost:5000/referral-health-signal:latest
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: servicebase
    ports:
    - containerPort: 9000
      protocol: TCP
    resources: {}
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: kube-api-access-c984r
      readOnly: true
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  enableServiceLinks: true
  nodeName: docker-desktop
  preemptionPolicy: PreemptLowerPriority
  priority: 0
  restartPolicy: Always
  schedulerName: default-scheduler
  securityContext: {}
  serviceAccount: default
  serviceAccountName: default
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  tolerations:
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  volumes:
  - name: secret-referral-health-signal
    secret:
      defaultMode: 420
      items:
      - key: aws-access-key-id
        path: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
      - key: aws-secret-access-key
        path: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
      secretName: referral-health-signal
  - name: kube-api-access-c984r
    projected:
      defaultMode: 420
      sources:
      - serviceAccountToken:
          expirationSeconds: 3607
          path: token
      - configMap:
          items:
          - key: ca.crt
            path: ca.crt
          name: kube-root-ca.crt
      - downwardAPI:
          items:
          - fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
            path: namespace
status:
  conditions:
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2022-08-31T22:32:28Z"
    status: "True"
    type: Initialized
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2022-08-31T22:32:30Z"
    status: "True"
    type: Ready
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2022-08-31T22:32:30Z"
    status: "True"
    type: ContainersReady
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2022-08-31T22:32:28Z"
    status: "True"
    type: PodScheduled
  containerStatuses:
  - containerID: docker://09d33da961a079adb4f6629eebd595dd6338b56f1f3ec779878503e9de04524f
    image: localhost:5000/referral-health-signal:latest
    imageID: docker-pullable://localhost:5000/referral-health-signal@sha256:d4dfeb70caa8145babcb025c287ec361bb1e920bf556cdec166d1d54f2136d1a
    lastState: {}
    name: servicebase
    ready: true
    restartCount: 0
    started: true
    state:
      running:
        startedAt: "2022-08-31T22:32:29Z"
  hostIP: 192.168.65.4
  phase: Running
  podIP: 10.1.0.64
  podIPs:
  - ip: 10.1.0.64
  qosClass: BestEffort
  startTime: "2022-08-31T22:32:28Z"
```

```
$ kubectl get svc
NAME              TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes        ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP          5d6h
rhs-servicebase   NodePort    10.103.51.237   <none>        9000:30001/TCP   40m
```

```
$ kubectl get endpoints
NAME              ENDPOINTS           AGE
kubernetes        192.168.65.4:6443   5d6h
rhs-servicebase   10.1.0.64:9000      40m
```

I can't understand what I'm missing in my config that's not allowing this to happen. Even when I exec into the pod and type `$ curl -i http://localhost:9000/` I don't get a response until I've turned on port forwarding - this is weird, right? At least within the container, it should be able to ping itself?

Please help !!

Comment: thru a service, node port allows internal access without forwarding, IP:PORT

Comment: please try this before any change, it should work http://10.103.51.237:9000

Comment: @jmvcollaborator Just tried it, doesn't work :(

Comment: im with my local cluster struggling i cant execute a pod interactive, getting a OCI error,

Comment: wondering why you cant access with ip:port given that it is a NodePort service and theres no name resolution. do you see something on the logs ?

Comment: I really don't know - kubectl logs show no issues at all!

Comment: I got the same problem, need to do port-forwarding or not be able to connect to the service